# FormRecognizer C# SDK not returning all data, treats Dynamic Tables as Document Field

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I created a custom model and it works well in the Form Recognizer Studio, in the JSON output under the "Document" it gives all the data points for the Fields I tagged and also all the data points for the Dynamic type Table I tagged.

[image]

The issue is the "result" from the C# SDK does not contain the Table data like the JSON output above, using the same model and sample.

```
AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = await client.StartAnalyzeDocumentAsync(modelID, streamContent);    
await operation.WaitForCompletionAsync();    
AnalyzeResult result = operation.Value;
```

Can see below it grabs the Fields without issue

[image]

but if you look at the TimeSheetDynamic below it is empty, unlike the JSON data which has all the data points in an array.

[image]

How do I access the data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? The API version needed to use is 2.1 and above to get the dynamic content to be recognized.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/whats-new?tabs=csharp

Comment: I am using the latest version of the API, well above the 2.1 so it has nothing to do with the API version, I am assuming they forgot or on the todo list to code the dynamic data load into the return model...??  FYI Installed version is 4.0.0-beta.3

Answer (score 0):

I followed the GitHub sample below to access the non-public members. Thanks Vinod for the sample.

```
 if (document.Fields.TryGetValue("Items", out DocumentField? itemsField))
            {
                if (itemsField.ValueType == DocumentFieldType.List)
                {
                    foreach (DocumentField itemField in itemsField.AsList())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Item:");

                        if (itemField.ValueType == DocumentFieldType.Dictionary)
                        {
                            IReadOnlyDictionary<string, DocumentField> itemFields = itemField.AsDictionary();

                            if (itemFields.TryGetValue("Description", out DocumentField? itemDescriptionField))
                            {
                                if (itemDescriptionField.ValueType == DocumentFieldType.String)
                                {
                                    string itemDescription = itemDescriptionField.AsString();

                                    Console.WriteLine($"  Description: '{itemDescription}', with confidence {itemDescriptionField.Confidence}");
                                }
                            }

                            if (itemFields.TryGetValue("Amount", out DocumentField? itemAmountField))
                            {
                                if (itemAmountField.ValueType == DocumentFieldType.Double)
                                {
                                    double itemAmount = itemAmountField.AsDouble();

                                    Console.WriteLine($"  Amount: '{itemAmount}', with confidence {itemAmountField.Confidence}");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

[Sample Code GitHub Link](https://github.com/vkurpad/azure-form-recognizer-samples/blob/main/v3.0_SDK/CSharpSDK/SDKSample_v3.0API/Program.cs)